# Echo php variable in the href link caption

Tags: php, html

I want to echo php variable in the link caption. like the following...

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<form action="new_question.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>">
<input type="submit" value="New Question">
</form>
<?php
include ("connection.php");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM question_table");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo <a href="http://www.example.com"><?php echo $row['question'] ?></a>;
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

but it doesn't work. Its a php syntax error i guess. I'm new in PHP. Please help me. I get this error.
[image]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The above code is fine

Comment: i'm working in Dreamweaver. The line number gets red as i type this.

Comment: Please post the error message. Without it we can't help you and this question will be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
echo <a href="http://www.example.com"><?php echo $row['question'] ?></a>;
```

To

```
echo "<a href=\"http://www.example.com\">" . $row['question'] . "</a>";
```

You are missing a pair of quotes.

Alternatively in your loop you can exit out of php and write your HTML like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
?>
  <a href="http://www.example.com"><?php echo $row['question'] ?></a>
  <br>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This way you don't have to try to echo out the HTML strings and having to worry about quotes and etc.

Comment: thank you sir! i tried your first method and it works. i can see where i went wrong. if you have time can you please explain a little bit about your second solution? i can't understand ": ?>" code and "<?php endwhile; ?>" code.

Comment: It is an alternative syntax for looping and conditions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 2):

or you can code like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"http://www.example.com\">";
echo $row['question'];
echo "</a>";
```

But it is for dummies.

Answer (score 1):

Error is down here:

```
echo <a href="http://www.example.com"><?php echo $row['question'] ?></a>;
```

You can code this line like that:

```
echo '<a href="http://www.example.com">'.$row['question'].'</a>';
```